# How to run Vite React based project on the root directory without /src folder

Tags: vite

So I had my Vite project that was working fine and had the /src folder where all my app was inside, and I wanted to give to it more structure and I dragged all the stuff from /src folder outside the root directory.

This is how it looks now:
[image: code structure]

My config:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

export default defineConfig({
  root: './',
  baseUrl: './',
  base: './',
  plugins: [react()],
});
```